# Trying to share an audio: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to share an audio file. This worked but now won't work for whatever reason.

This is the code I'm using on my MainActivity:

```
        val uuid = stompaiMessage.playbackMessage.sharePlayback.uuid
        Log.d(TAG, "gonna share playback $uuid")
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "$uuid.wav")
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
        Log.d(TAG, "Playback Share: intent with uri: $uri")
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        startActivity(intent)
```

This is the error:

```
E/MethodChannel#com.myapp.channel( 1949): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.myapp.flutter_app.provider/external/Android/data/com.myapp.flutter_app/files/47c4a08c-e239-4d58-83b5-65f4ed2f2797.wav typ=audio/* flg=0x1 }
E/MethodChannel#com.myapp.channel( 1949):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2030)
E/MethodChannel#com.myapp.channel( 1949):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1685)
```

I don't get which activity was not found. There's only one activity and it's MainActivity.

Comment: What was no found it's an app installed on your device that can open/play audio. I guess it worked on other devices that have media players.

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard MIME type. Or, do not provide a MIME type at all, and let the system get one from the `ContentProvider` for that `Uri`.